# celery python exception passing

Tags: python, exception, celery

How to pass custom exception classes that inherit BaseException and celery' exception handling results, that is, pass custom exceptions or python native exceptions to celery

When I want to pass the custom exception class to the celery task definition through raise, and then carry out different processing logic through different exceptions, but when the exception is passed to the celery task, I encounter a difficult error message Exception information must be have exception type

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)